# Debugging a run-once registry command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-registry, windows-domain

I'm having trouble getting my runonce command to actually run on login after I promote my server to AD. I've gotten my autologin to work just fine but my registry command won't run on reboot, code below:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" `
-Name '!continueADConfig' `
-Value "c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Normal -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit $scriptpath -primaryNTP $primaryNTP -secondaryNTP $secondaryNTP -rootDomainName $rootDomainName -netBiosName $netBiosName -staticIp $staticIp -subnetPrefix $subnetPrefix -defaultGateway $defaultGateway"
```

resulting in a runonce !continueADConfig value of `c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Normal -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\promotion.ps1 -primaryNTP 10.230.62.10 -secondaryNTP 10.231.62.10 -rootDomainName example.com -netBiosName mynetbios -staticIp 192.168.5.10 -subnetPrefix 24 -defaultGateway 192.168.5.1`

I've checked the runonce key after startup and the values populate correctly, I've even copy/pasted the resulting command into both powershell and cmd.exe with success, it just won't run from the registry. I am running autologin into the domain's administrator account too....

Comment: Download `procmon` from sysinternals, enable boot logging, reboot and search if the registry key has been accessed or not. If it has, there's either a problem reading the key or a problem running it. Both cases can be verified from the logging.

Comment: `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents` might be invisible (or access denied to) in login time. Place the  `promotion.ps1` to a commonly accessible folder.

Comment: What kinds of folders are commonly accessible? I placed it at the root of c, `C:\` and it still didn't work